# Separate html return data in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

With the code below is possible to get separate values, using the variable `data`. I have inside 2 variables `content` and `pagination`, and I want to separate them.

I need and answer that doesn't use JSON.

```
                  jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo DOMAIN ?>inc/ajax_content/sort-jobs-content.php",
                data: "id_select="+id_select+"&selected_value="+value,
                dataType : "html",
                complete: function () {  },
                success: function(data){


                }
            });
```

Comment: Why not JSON? Seems to be ideal for this task?

Comment: I have a lot of html with php to load , and will be hard for me to declare as JSON array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@partoa Thank you for your help i finally fixed my problem , just i used `closest`  function , because `find` is showing finded div and the rest is empty , anyway thank you for your help  !

```
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo DOMAIN ?>inc/ajax_content/sort-jobs-content.php",
                data: name_selected+"="+value_element ,
                dataType : "html",
                complete: function () { },
                success: function(data){
                    var obj = jQuery(data);
                    var content_records = obj.closest('div#content_records').clone();
                    var pages = obj.closest('#pages').clone();


                    jQuery("div#records_content").html(content_records);
                    jQuery("div#pages").html(pages);

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON would be best. But if you insist, how about this?

```
success: function(data){
    var obj = $(data);
    var pagination = obj.find('.pagenation').clone();
    var content = obj.find('.content').clone();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help . But i tried and is not working , result returned in firebug console is `[]`